# WPF: how to call method by setting tag of a dynamically created buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8

3 problems in my WPF(window phone) simple project. I have spent lot of time by solving it but no specific result found..

In my cs file I have Created bunch of dynamic buttons...I crated with for loop and set tags for each dynamic button.

My cs File code is here.

```
  private void Grid_View_Btn_1_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {



        //Grid ButtonsAddition
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            string[] Trade = new string[] { "Portfolio Display", "Trade Idea Entry", "Trade Idea Monitor", "Historical Performance", "Intraday Performance", "Stock Performance" };

            StackPanel panel = new StackPanel();
            panel.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical;

            //panel.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
            //panel.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;

            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < Trade.Length; i++)
            {
                Button btn = new Button() { Content = Trade[i] };
                btn.Margin = new Thickness(0, -10, 0, -10);



                var brush = new ImageBrush();
                brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:/Users/HafizArslan/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/AimPass/AimPass/Images/tabbar_btn_blue.png", UriKind.Relative));
                btn.Background = brush;


                btn.Width = 190;
                btn.Height = 75;
                btn.FontSize = 14;
                btn.FontWeight = light;
                btn.FontStretch = Fill;
                btn.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                btn.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
                //   btn.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(15);
                btn.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 1, 1);
                btn.Tag = i.ToString();
                btn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(abc_click);


                panel.Children.Add(btn);

            }
            grid.Children.Add(panel);

        });
    }
    private void abc_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
```

There are 6 buttons creted.
the problem is I want to perform different actions with button...I have set Tags but I dont know how can I access an actions with buttons Tag..?

I mean I want something like this...!!

```
     private void abc_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

  // If(btn.Tag==1)
   {
   //Some Code Here
   }   
    else 
     if(btn.Tag==2) {
                    //Perform other Function
                    }
    }   Etc.....?
```

and other problem is I have made a image brush..Assign exact path of image...for every created button background....But Image is not attached...

Kindly tell me about these 2 problems...

Comment: I suggest to change the infrastructure and deal with databinding/ItemsControl.

Comment: @Felice Pollano I have done lot of work...I think its not possible dear....kindly tell me if you have solution for this...or any method..?

Comment: The suggestion I gave you is what I would do.

Comment: @FelicePollano is right, but I'm not as forgiving and kind. I will say your code is HORRIBLE and you need to delete all that and learn to use WPF properly. Delete all your code and use an `ItemsControl`.

Comment: yup..:) But Dear I have to make all these things dynamically...so that I can change (values/buttons length) at any time...

Comment: @user3061129 XAML's idea of `dynamically` is very different from crappy technologies such as winforms. in XAML, if you want to create items dynamically you use an `ItemsControl`. My point still stands. Delete all that horrible code and learn to use XAML properly.

Comment: @HighCore :) someone else sai, here but don't remember where, when people start to use the dinamically word, they did not get how XAML works :)

Comment: @HighCore May b you are right...I am new in Xaml,wpf.....Slowly I 'll improve myself in these tools....this is my first simple project dear....So

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have sender in handler, you can `type cast sender to button` and `access Tag property` from it:

```
private void abc_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Button button = (Button)sender;
   if(Convert.ToInt32(button.Tag) == 1)
   {
      .....
   }
}
```

Comment: operater "==" can't be applied to operands of type object to int...This error is coming..?

Comment: `button.Tag` is of type object. You need to cast it to int first. Check updated answer.

Comment: Dear this does not show any error...but after compiling project...when I prees dynamic button..this gives error...some thing like this...and stop working..            An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in AimPass.DLL but was not handled in user code

Comment: Oh my fault, i didn't tried it before posting. Try the updated one.

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop, you can associate handler to the button.

Such as:

```
                Button btn = new Button() { Content = Trade[i] };
                btn.Margin = new Thickness(0, -10, 0, -10);
                if(<something>)
                   btn.Click += YourEventHandler1;

                if(<something2>)
                  btn.Click += YourEventHandler2;
```

If you want to access tag property, you need to cast the sender to Button, as so:

```
  private void abc_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       var btn = (Button)sender;
    }
```

Comment: I think you are suggesting that for each button I have to make an event....???  Dear I have lot of such type of loop in my project....Its much difficult to do this...??

Answer (score 0):

if for all created buttons the event is same then One approach could be to get the tag in the event like this

```
int tag=Convert.ToInt32((sender as Button).Tag);
```

now use a switch

```
switch(tag)
{
case 1:
//Action
break;
case 2:
//Acrion
break;
//more cases
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: switch is also showing error... int tag = Convert.ToInt32((sender as Button).Tag);  where i have to put this..??  in my loop or in my event handler..?

Comment: add this in the event handler, and you can keep tag as a string and make the cases of string values.. anything could help

Comment: make that S of switch small :D

Answer (score 0):

you should go with this

```
var tag=((sender as Button).Tag).ToString();
////now use a switch

Switch(tag)
{
case "1":
//Action
break;
case "2":
//Acrion
break;
//more cases
}
```

hope this helps.